# preview the uploaded .pdf file in ASP web form

Tags: javascript

I am building an ASP webform application. I used

```
<asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="fubillPhoto" onchange="showPreviewBill(this);" />
```

...to upload a pdf file. I want users to be able to review the uploaded file before submitting the form.
My idea is to create an element. When the user clicks on it a new tab open with PDF file. unfortunately I could not apply my idea... Here is my code:

HTML

```
    <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="fuBillPhoto" onchange="showPreviewBill(this);" />
    <div runat="server" id="divPdfBill" class="hidden"> 
    <a runat="server" id="pdfBilllink" href="#"  target="_blank">click here</a>
    </div>
```

=====

Javascript

```
function showPreviewBill(input) {
var pdfLink = document.getElementById('#<%=pdfBilllink.ClientID %>');
var file = document.querySelector('#<%=fubillPhoto.ClientID %>').files[0];
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = function () {
if (reader.result) {
$('#<%=pdfBilllink.ClientIDMode %>').attr("href", reader.result);
$('#<%=divPdfBill.ClientID %>').attr("class", "");
}
}
$('#<%=pdfBilllink.ClientIDMode %>').attr("href", reader.result);
```

It does not work! Please advise.

Comment: When you say review the uploaded form what do you mean? See the name of it? View an image of it? See the file details of it?

Comment: i want the user to see the details. for example, add link.. if the user click the link the PDF open in new window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Load data uri from input file control use javascript file api.
2. Convert data uri to binary.
3. Show binary data in canvas using PDF.js.

here is  a reference on how to do that with code

[link] https://forums.asp.net/t/2062665.aspx?Preview+pdf+file+before+upload

code from above reference website

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#pdfInp").change(function () {
if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function (e) {
showInCanvas(e.target.result);
}
reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
}
});

function convertDataURIToBinary(dataURI) {
var BASE64_MARKER = ';base64,';
var base64Index = dataURI.indexOf(BASE64_MARKER) + BASE64_MARKER.length;
var base64 = dataURI.substring(base64Index);
var raw = window.atob(base64);
var rawLength = raw.length;
var array = new Uint8Array(new ArrayBuffer(rawLength));

for (i = 0; i < rawLength; i++) {
array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
}
return array;
}

function showInCanvas(url) {
// See README for overview 
'use strict';
// Fetch the PDF document from the URL using promises 
var pdfAsArray = convertDataURIToBinary(url);
PDFJS.getDocument(pdfAsArray).then(function (pdf) {
// Using promise to fetch the page 
pdf.getPage(1).then(function (page) {
var scale = 1.5;
var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);
// Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions 
var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.height = viewport.height;
canvas.width = viewport.width;
// Render PDF page into canvas context 
var renderContext = {
canvasContext: context,
viewport: viewport
};
page.render(renderContext);
});
});
}
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" >
    <p>
        <input type='file' id="pdfInp" />
        <canvas id="the-canvas" style="border:1px solid black"></canvas>
    </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="fubillPhoto" onchange="showPreviewBill(this);" 
/>`enter code here`
```